# Ruby on Rails (3) hiding parts of the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 3 web application.

I have a table named `User` with a coulmn named `role`. I am looking for the best way to hide parts of the view from users that have the "wrong" role for those parts of the view.

For example I want all users to be able to see the users `index` page, but i want only users with a role - `admin` to be able to edit other users.

So first I block the `edit` action using `filter_by`, but what I also want is make the `edit` button not to appear.

The current user is saved in the session, so checking the user role is very simple.

What I am asking, is there an easy way to do so besides the obvious `if` statement before each button I want to hide. I would think that rails would have an easy way to do this type of thing, I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wanted to clean it up a tiny bit you could write yourself an application helper:

```
  def if_admin(user)
    if(user.is_admin? && block_given?)
      yield
      return
    end
  end
```

then in your view you could write:

```
  <% if_admin(@user) do %>
    <some admin only html />
  <% end %>
```

Comment: There's no `user` argument to that method and it's more performant not to capture the block as an argument. You'd probably want to do it like this: `def display_if_admin(user); yield if block_given? && user.admin?; end;`

Comment: Then what `user` would the function use? Where do i set the specific user?

Comment: @nayish you pass the user object that you grab in your controller to the `if_admin()` method in the view. The `is_admin?` method would be defined in your User model class.

Comment: would this method be available for use in any view including out of the User view?

Comment: yes if you put it in `application_helper.rb`. Any other helper and it will only be automatically available to that helper's corresponding controller. You will need to always have the user object to pass to it though.

Comment: I wish there was a better way to do this. What if there are 8 different possibilities? Like, if_admin, if_moderator, if_banned, if_warned, if_logged_in, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use Devise and CanCan.

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
- https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Here is a RailCast tutorial

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for more of a default built in type answer.

Comment: @nayish There is nothing "built in" to Ruby or Rails for this. You can write your own authorization system or use an existing one, like CanCan, which Nerian linked.